# Why are some columns not recognized as numeric even with CSVT?

Tags: qgis, csv

I have problems importing a .csv file.

Some Values of the file are not supposed to be formated in text style, but in number style, thus i created an additional .csvt file like explained [here](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/).

Both files with exactly the same name and the same location are created. The number of columns is the same and I add the .csv file with the "Add Delimited Text Layer" tool. Nevertheless I am not able to choose any columns for a graduated symbology.

My .csv file includes 12 rows, of which the 5th, 11th, and 12th column consist numbers.
My .csvt file therefore looks like that:

*"String","String","String","String","Integer","String","String","String","String","String","Integer","Integer"*

I tried to create it with the standard editor from Windows and Notepad++.

What mistake may I have made?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "Add delimited text layer" tool does not interpret the CSVT. Only "add vector layer" needs a CSVT. Basically, "add delimited text layer" tries to make a best guess and it usually does very well recognizing numeric values. One of the reasons to use "add vector layer" is that "add delimited text layer" requires a geometry column.

Does your CSV contain a geometry or x and y columns? Then use "add delimited text layer".

If your CSV does not contain any coordinates/geometry, use "add vector layer".

As to why the numeric values are not recognized by "add delimited text layer", please post your CSV or at least a sample (first few lines). If even one line in the file contains a text in the "numeric" column, the tools will default back to String.