# CSV handling in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, csv

I am using QGIS 2.4.0 and sadly it seems that QGIS imported csv files are somewhat bugged. I cannot use imported csv files the same way as shapefiles. It seems that sometimes it is easier to import the file and then just save the csv file inside QGIS as a shapefile and import it again to make it work. 
The reasons I am saying this are the following:

- I cannot save the style files associates with csv files.
- In properties tab type and typename are always double and the lenght and precision are always 0
- Calculations are not possible since some columns are not seen as containing Real or Natural numbers.

Once saved as shapefile I can suddenly do everything I need. So am I missing something or is there no other way to not to have this intermediary saving step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You experience the limitations of the csv driver. Saving as shapefile and working on with that is really the best opportunity.

For the data type issue, you can create a csvt file to predefine the data type of the columns:

http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html

http://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/

You have to use `Add Vector Layer` instead of `Add delimited Text` to utilize the .csvt:

[Why are some columns not recognized as numeric even though I have a CSVT?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45005/why-are-some-columns-not-recognized-as-numeric-even-though-i-have-a-csvt)