# Editing CSV tables in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv

I am trying to join a CSV table to a shapefile in QGIS 2.12.0. I have exported a table from Excel to CSV format, but when opening the table I noticed that my unique ID field in Excel is in text format, is changed to number in QGIS. Since my shapefile has that same ID field as a text string I cannot join them. I have tried to change the format to string but it does not let me. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Changing CSV layer attribute value from text to number in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29606/changing-csv-layer-attribute-value-from-text-to-number-in-qgis)

Comment: create a csvt file. more infos here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45005/why-are-some-columns-not-recognized-as-numeric-even-though-i-have-a-csvt

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Field Calculator (open the Attribute Table, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) to convert numbers to strings. The following command should do the job :

```
 tostring( "ID" )
```

(replace ID with the actual name of your ID field).

Comment: Make sure there are no spaces or other "notnumbers" in your fields when doing it the other way around with to_int or to_real.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **add spreadsheet layer** plugin to bring in the CSV. You can then set the field types on import.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know several methods to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the .csvt technic. Check this short tutorial: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html?highlight=csvt