# Why the table fields imported from a .csv file have a length of zero?

Tags: qgis

I've imported a .csv file (with relative .csvt) in QGIS 2.8.4 adding a delimited text layer... the table was correctly been imported but the table fields have a length of zero... the fields types instead have been correctly read from the .csvt, which obviously specifies also the fields lengths.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The fields lengths are correctly read simply dragging and dropping the .csv file into the layer panel... (?!?)

Comment: Could you maybe make a printscreen of the problem?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data and csvt?

Comment: Thanks @AndreJ I didn't know that QGIS doesn't read the .csvt with "Add delimited text"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [gdal.org/drv_csv](http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html), you can define width and precision in the csvt file.

**BUT:**

According to [Why are some columns not recognized as numeric even though I have a CSVT?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45005/why-are-some-columns-not-recognized-as-numeric-even-though-i-have-a-csvt), QGIS does **NOT** read the csvt with `Add delimited text`. Instead, it makes some kind of educated guess about the data types

Try `Add Vector Layer` instead. Draging and dropping the csv file from an explorer window to the legend will do the same, as you experienced.